# How to write Java-style for loop with colon operator in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, range

I want to write a Java-style `for` loop such as the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i-1; ++j) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
    }
}
```

The output of running the above code would be

```
2 1
3 1
3 2
```

My attempt to code this in `R` is the following:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
        print(sprintf('%d %d', i, j))
    }
}
```

However, running this `R` code gives the output

```
[1] "1 1"
[1] "1 0"
[1] "2 1"
[1] "3 1"
[1] "3 2"
```

I realize that this is happening because `1:0 = c(1,0)`.
Using `seq(1,0)` does not work either because `seq(1,0) = c(1,0)`.
What is the right way to write these two `for` loops?

Comment: For the benefit of us R users that aren't that familiar with Java, could you explain what the output should be?

Comment: OK, I have done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the inner `for` with a `while`:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    j <- 1
    while (j < i) {
        print(sprintf('%d %d', i, j))
        j <- j + 1
    }
}
```

Assuming Java's `for` is anything like C's, this is basically what happens there as well, semantically speaking.

Comment: Ok, if that's what it's supposed to do, then you could run the inner for loop through `seq_len(i-1)` as well, I suppose.

Comment: That is a good suggestion that works as well. I didn't know about the existence of the `seq_len` function before!

Comment: @ILiketoCode `seq_len` (and `seq_along`) are in fact specifically intended to be used in places like for loop specifications in order to avoid bugs arising from the use of `:`. Their use in that context is often considered "good practice".

Comment: @joran I see! Thank you for telling me about these useful commands.